# code shrinking not working When relying on a new remote library

Tags: android, build, proguard

1. the remote library (xxx.aar) that doesn't have a proguard.txt file
2. my local proguard-rules.pro file does not contain anything like ‘-dontshrink’
3. application module build.gradle content:

```
    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources false
            minifyEnabled true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            ndk {
                abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
            }
        }
   }
```

4. project gradle.properties content:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608M

# tips：R8 is not used
android.enableD8.desugaring= true

# enable for androidx
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

5. extra info:

```
 // 版本管理
 compileSdkVersion    : 29,
 buildToolsVersion    : "29.0.3",

 // 目标版本
 minSdkVersion        : 14,
 targetSdkVersion     : 29,


 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
 }
```

is someone met this question?  take me some advices , thanks.

Answer (score 0):

omg, The problem is that the remote library (xxx.aar) depends on another aar with a proguard.txt file, and proguard.txt contains '-dontshrink'.